# npm install optionalDependencies but no devDependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install

Using `npm install`, is there a way to install optionalDependencies but not install devDependencies?

1. production deps
2. dev deps
3. optional deps

So here is how I see it:

5. `npm install` => installs 1,2,3
6. `npm install --production` => installs 1
7. `npm install --no-optional` => installs 1, 2

I am looking to install 1 and 3, though.

Something like this, maybe?

`npm install --production --optional`

?